# Sticky notes app for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, note-taking

I'm looking for a simple-to-run, simple-to-use sticky notes application for Ubuntu 15.10. It should have the following features:

- Ability to add, edit and delete notes.
- Ability to move notes around
- **Ability to have notes on top of other windows**
- Note text/position should be maintained after restart
- Should work with Ubuntu 15.10 under Unity.

Comment: Xpad Been a while since the last time I used ubuntu, but I gess `sudo apt-get install xpad`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Tomboy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tomboy&searchon=names&suite=wily&section=all).

It has features that allows syncing to all your computers and devices.  There are a couple of syncing services but I use the `graupel` plugin of [Owncloud](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&section=all&arch=any&keywords=owncloud&searchon=names).

Installation is simple:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chromium or Google Chrome on Ubuntu, you call install the packaged app [Whenever](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whenever-sticky-notes-wit/nfbcejefjldiddbganfjdlmgiafffhpd).

It meets most of your criteria, except the note text and position after restart.